# Completion block using GCD

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, grand-central-dispatch, nsoperationqueue

I am developing an app that requires a completion block and a "barrier" functionality.
As far as I know, `NSOperation` API has a `completionBlock` property and GCD API has the `dispatch_barrier_(a)sync` function to handle the barrier needs.

What should I do in order to accomplish both of the needs?
Thanks!

Comment: Please don't use internet slang / acronyms here on SO (specifically, 'ASAIK'), as they might not be understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dispatch_group should have all the pieces you need. Just dispatch_group_async/dispatch_group_enter for your work units, then dispatch_group_notify for your completion handler.